# A riddle wrapped in a mystery inside an enigma

Tags: cipher

The following message can be unambiguously decoded to reveal an eleven letter word. It can be deciphered with pen and paper, although knowing a bit of Python would probably help.

What is the word?

> o83AfLftzPrpZPdflFo4AFlhTFIeOpvoRd5f5lFDfPrqnFudFfiSa
>   tHFiSapbVOp0vorvmApD4fLFpBvo1oaiEofF2lhTdFprpBvo2FieO
>   9dFlFdfPrfD3ifaPFieOoaiEko8iPhODfLfpb32vODfPrpVorPbvO
>   iF2c9pIPhoDFLff83DifaSFtOacoNQvmAppvqzUeOaftDFPrdf2lF
>   PVODieHOvA3QKQzUeDFp5rvaqKOp7zprpOcVdiehopBvodFprfD30

<sup>(Note: The original text had to be edited, but it still available in the [edit history](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/5389/4) if anyone needs it.)</sup>

I can't think of any more clues I can offer without giving the whole thing away, but the answer can be obtained without any fancy arithmetic.

---

### Clue 1:

> Don't eat the fish

### Clue 2:

> Try the bacon instead

### Clue 3:

> And for dessert, perhaps the Cranberry Tart or Stilton Cheese?

### Clue 4:

> ***The keyword is important***

Comment: 1 hour and no answer it has to be good ... or do you really mean that weekend comment

Comment: Is it in English? A dictionary word?

Comment: I've created a chatroom: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18874/a-riddle-wrapped-in-a-mystery-inside-an-enigma
as I have a few things to paste that might help other people get started - although I'm basically nowhere. :(

Comment: @AE I'm sure you've seen this word before :-)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage, ah, but is it in my computer's dictionary file? ;-)

Comment: @AE *(whistling nonchalantly)* ♪♬

Comment: argh! you're killing me! ;)

Comment: @AE - This is what we call a cyanide puzzle...

Comment: I dont know what to make of this community where a question like this receives 3 nett up votes and things like "you are dreaming" get 40... I am sure something is not right

Comment: @skv, I agree that questions like this deserve more recognition.

Comment: Would you mind adding any hints... now that after almost 24 hours there are no responses despite many attempts :)

Comment: @skv OK, one clue added...

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Are the extra numbers in the cipher useful or just placeholders?

Comment: Is it a 4 letter word???

Comment: @stackErr No, the numbers in the cipher text were just a red herring. (I wish I hadn't put them in now!) The answer to the puzzle is an eleven letter word.

Comment: are the remaining numbers in Joes post a Book cipher? :P and just a shot in the dark, after finding a nice reference to your user id...is the word "bone-breaker" :P

Comment: @stackErr You're getting warm...

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I think I have it!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Continuing from Joes answer...basically all credit goes to him, since he only missed this part:

The unsolved part from Joes answer:

> 78 19 25 9 92 29 54 1 95 49 6 247 4 2 149 45 5 7 199 11 62 63 179 47 14 50 23 163 52

I did this:

> I googled Jumblies and found a poem with the same name. [The Jumblies](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/241166#poem)

.

> Taking the corresponding words from that poem you will get the following:

.

> "go of on did the in....."

What they all have in common is that they are all:

> Preposition!

Edit:

This could be wrong I created a script to double check: http://jsfiddle.net/fz29ruoy/1/

and it gives me the following words:

> go of On did, Jumblies on be They heads every a they sea went said, round in Sieve, Their a big, But In round, went one could the ‘You’ll

And taking the first letter of each word:

> goOd Job The atswsr  iS  Tabbirwocty

And I am guessing there are some typos or I have mistakes in my code:

> Good Job the answer is:

.

> Jabberwocky!!

Comment: You're ***so*** close to cracking it. In fact, the distance between you and the answer is about this long: – (according to my precise measurements :-D)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage finally got it!!

Comment: Hooray! “ヽ(´▽｀)ノ” Well done. [I updated your JSFiddle to show how to get the answer from the book code](http://jsfiddle.net/fz29ruoy/2/).

Comment: @squeamishossifrage thanks! I was trying to find what went wrong in the code :P. And like I said, I think Joe should get most of the credit not me. I did the easy part

Answer (score 12):

OK, so I'll post my working so far. I'm plodding along slowly with it :-)

**Update:** This working is all done with the original ciphertext. The same logic can be applied to the *correct* ciphertext and you'll end up at the numbers that the OP supplied part-way through the solve.

---

The second hint is a kind of cipher... how do we utilise it?

> Convert lowercase letters to a and uppercase to b. Treat numbers as spaces. Decode it with the Bacon cipher.

Decrypting the first line like this gives us a translated ciphertext of

> a  babaaabaabbaaaba bbaabbbabaaaba a abbabaaabaabaaba

which in turn, decodes to

> KEY WOR DIS

Continuing the remaining 4 lines in the same way, we get the following ciphertext and message:

> a  babaaabaabbaaaba bbaabbbabaaaba a abbabaaabaabaaba
>  abbabaaabba aaaaabab abbabaa aaabaab aababaaabaa baab
>  ababaabaab aaabbaabaaabaa ababbabaaa  abbabaabaabaab
>  ab a abbaabbbaa  baaabbabaaabbaabaaaaababaaabbbaaa ab
>  bbbbaabbab bbbababba aaaabba aaaababaaaaaabaaabaaab
>
>  KEY WORD IS JUMBLIES REVERSE LINES THEN DECRYPT PLAYFAIR

---

By following the first directive, we now have the ciphertext of

> fEhkQzkQavrPfDFl5f5dRovpOeIFThlFA4oFlfdASifHtpzTfL38f
>  AooE2ifOeifRpFdr2PfdGmtn1ocAtOVb4PfLfdpam0vROvpoEiFQn
>  OcaOovBprOvPRp23fdoEiFOvBp8ohPiokEiaOOeif3PafIdfRoVp9
>  Qf2oeiFRPfdtFaOeuvhpItrEUvheIaOTfavU38fnQOEifOHp9i2Pc
>  03FidfRpfdOvbpoheOrZrovp7qNOcaot5fSAmVfLFD3OhEOrzPZQV

Now, this is the evil part.

> In Playfair encryption, J gets translated to I, so our keyword is actually IUMBLES.

Decrypting with this, we get a string containing digits written out (one, two) and a lot of `q` characters which split up groups of digits (it's not unusual for `q` to be omitted from this kind of cipher, so they probably represent spaces). It isn't clear just yet what these numbers mean, or whether any should be combined together.

> eightxhrexqonenineqtwofiveqnineqninesevenqtwonineqfivefiveqoneqonehundredqfournineqsixqtwofivethreeqfourqtwoqonefivefourqfourfiveqfiveqsevenqtwoohfiveqoneoneqsixfourqsixfiveqonexightfiveqfoursevenqonefourqfiftyqtwothreeqonesixnineqfiftytwox

The numbers are:

> 83 19 25 9 97 29 55 1 100 49 6 253 4 2 154 45 5 7 205 11 64 65 185 47 14 50 23 169 52

---

**But** these are wrong (@OP HOW COULD YOU!?) so we need these ones instead, provided by the OP :P

> 78 19 25 9 92 29 54 1 95 49 6 247 4 2 149 45 5 7 199 11 62 63 179 47 14 50 23 163 52

Interestingly, all the deciphering we've done so far has been purely alphabetical - the Bacon deciphering was done with upper/lowercase letters and we ignored the numbers as all characters in Bacon are comprised of 5 a/bs, and the Playfair decryption only uses letter digraphs, again discarding numbers.

> There happen to be 5 digits in each of the 5 lines of the ciphertext (and they remained consistent between old/new ciphertexts):
>  83 4 5 5
>  0 4 1 2 2
>  9 3 8 32
>  2 9 83 2
>  3 5 7 30

Comment: You've just about cracked it. Well done :-)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage for being so close, it feels like I'm nowhere xD They aren't ASCII codes, converting to binary and text is a dud, trying mod 26 and ASCII is garbage, reversing the digits and stuff goes nowhere, adding them or multiplying them produces nothing, and I can't even think of a sensible way to reduce 29 numbers to 11 so I'm expecting that the whole thing will translate into a sentence. Not sure how though, right now

Comment: I'm afraid you've gone slightly adrift there...

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I appear to have found some more numbers... the number-plot thickens!

Comment: I've added one more clue. Good luck :-)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage that just complicates things even more xD The best I can do is that a "Bombe" is a dessert and is the name given to the machine used to decrypt Enigma messages, tying in to the title. The Enigma encryption machines had 29-key keyboard, there are 29 numbers in the Playfair plaintext. How that correlates to any numbers/letters though is beyond me

Comment: ...and now you're completely at sea :-(

Comment: @squeamishossifrage are the unused numbers from the initial ciphertext still relevant (we haven't used them yet) or were they just used as padding to throw us off the Bacon cipher?

Comment: Interesting that the first and last number are multiples of 26...

Comment: @stackErr I noticed that, and wondered if they were some kind of delimiter, but I think I accidentally deleted the comment. The OP basically said "nope" to it, IIRC

Comment: @stackErr Yep. I've also tried all kinds of silly conversions to the numbers (reversing them, alternating, counting letters of the written-out forms, etc) :P Also tried doing Caesarian shifts on the letters without any joy. Other than `String.fromCharCode` (JS) or `% 26` into a substitution cipher, I'm struggling

Comment: Have you figured out clue 3?

Comment: @stackErr no. I can't stand stilton, though

Comment: @joe I think we might have to use Polybius cipher... the 5x5 pattern again. Havent figured out a working configuration.

Comment: Or a Pollux cipher?

Comment: @stackErr I tried pollux but again, couldn't make anything sensible from it. Not tried polybius because I can't see how it corresponds :-/

Comment: @Joe Solved! after reading Lens hint.

Comment: @Len yeah that poem is definitely related!!